# Can't retrieve Fb user object (email, etc) only Id and Name

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been trying to retrieve the Facebook email and the whole User object according the Facebook API guide.

I'm trying with this code but, it only returns the Id and Name

```
(function(d,s,id) {  
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  
    if(d.getElementById(id)) return;  
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  
    js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";  
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);  
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));  

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {  
    FB.init({  
        appId : 'xxxxx',  
        cookie : true,  
        xfbml : true,  
        version : 'v2.4'  
    });  
}  
function ingresar() {
    FB.login(function(response){  
        validarUsuario();  
    }, {scope: 'public_profile, email, user_friends',
        return_scopes: true});  
}  
function validarUsuario() {  
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {  
        if(response.status == 'connected') {  
            FB.api('/me', function(response) { 
                console.log(response);
            });  

        } else if(response.status == 'not_authorized') {  
            alert('Debes autorizar la app!');  
        } else {  
            alert('Debes ingresar a tu cuenta de Facebook!');  
        }  
    });  
}
```

I've also tried to call the FB.api('/UserId') but it returns the same.

Notes: Email permission is by default in Fb app settings so, It's configured already to be retrieved, it's included in the facebook permissions popup.

Hope somebody can help me!